# Show/hide buttons when clicked

Tags: javascript, function, button, show-hide

I want two buttons, that are oppositely shown or hidden when clicked. (i.e., via style:display=none|block;).

Initially, button1 would be display:block and button2 would be display:none.

When you click button1, it would switch button2 to be display:block and button1 to be display:none.

I know this is probably somthing so simple, please excuse my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we create two buttons. Give them id attributes so we have an alias by which to access them:

```
<button id="first">Click</button> <button id="second">Second</button>
```

Set the CSS as you defined:

```
#first  { display: block; }
#second { display: none;  }
```

Then comes the JS. We access both elements through their IDs using a function called `document.getElementById()`. This will return the element with the specified ID.

```
var first = document.getElementById( 'first' ),
    second = document.getElementById( 'second' );
```

And now we can make a `toggle` function. Here is the concept: If the `display` attribute of the first element is "block", then we change it to "none" and we change the latter to "block". And vice-versa. Here it is:

```
function toggle() {

    if ( first.style.display === "block" ) {

        first.style.display = "none";
        second.style.display = "block";

    } else { // switch back

        first.style.display = "block";
        second.style.display = "none";

    }

}
```

Then we set the event handlers in the HTML thusly:

```
<button id="first" onclick="toggle();">First</button>
<button id="second" onclick="toggle();">Second</button>
```

or we can do it using JS:

```
first.onclick = toggle;
second.onclick = toggle;
```

I like the second better, we'll stick with that,

And there you have it. You can find a working example here -- http://jsfiddle.net/twEK5/

Comment: Really appreciate the way you broke it down for me.  Its exactly what i needed.  Easy to understand and straight forward.  Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

if you are okay with using jquery, this is quite easy to perform, you can simply set the css of the objects with the `css(key, value)` function, e.g. [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GJCy9/)

Alternatively with pure js: [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MVQwL/)

Comment: Thanks...for the response and info.